Layer "sequential_29" expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors
I am trying to use GridSearchCV on a trained model. But the following error occurs:

Layer "sequential_29" expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=100>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=100>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>]

I have searched everywhere but I didn't succeed to run GridSearchCV.
My model looks like :
def cnn_model(size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16,3,input_shape=size, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32,3,input_shape=size, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(16,3,input_shape=size, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.compile('adam', loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    #print(model.summary())
    return model

I trained the model with "fit" function and a shape of (16149, 100, 100, 1) for X_train. And there isn't any problem.
Now when I tried to run GridSearchCV with the same data :
model_wopad2 = KerasClassifier(lambda:model_wopad(IMAGE_SIZE), verbose = 1)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model_wopad2, param_grid = param_grid, scoring="accuracy", verbose = 1)
grid_results = grid.fit(X_train,y_train, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

I obtain the above error.
Do you have any idea of how to reshape the data (or other) in order to run this function ?
I also saw that we can create our own GridSearch function but I didn't succeed either
I already tried to change the shape of the model in the 'KerasClassifier' function.
I tried to reshape my X_train data but didn't know what's the problem in the actual shape
